# Possible reason for not able to create a azure sql server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

While I am trying to create a database in azure and I don't have any option to create new server.

[image]

Comment: Do I need any admin privilege or subscription to create a server in  azure.??

Comment: You should post this to ServerFault, not StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question. And no, you don't need any specific admin privileges, aside from your email being linked to the subscription (I'm assuming this is your subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reason

1. If you use your own subscription, it means your subscription doesn't have the ability to create SQL server or Virtual machine
2. If you under someone subscription (you are not the subscription owner), it means you role not "high" enough to do it (create SQL server), you should contact your supervisor

Comment: Thank you .... 
I was just a user and my admin added role for me to create server.